# Спарсить после конкретного класса в Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, у меня парсится сайт, который содержит такой html:

```
<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/0/">1</a></li>
<li class="current"><a> 2 </a></li>
<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/80/"> 3 </a></li>
```

Надо спарсить все class="1NPSa", но именно после class="current"

```
list = soup.findAll("a", class_="1NPSa")
print(list)
[<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/0/">1</a></li>
 <li class="current"><a> 2 </a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/80/"> 3 </a></li>]
```

**Как это реализовать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код с этим справится:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = """
<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/0/">1</a></li>
<li class="current"><a> 2 </a></li>
<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/80/"> 3 </a></li>
<li class=""><a class="1NPSa" href="/models/81/"> 4 </a></li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')
current = soup.find("li", class_="current")
found = [x.find("a") for x in current.find_next_siblings("li")]
print(found)
```

P.S. Не делайте имена переменных совпадающими со стандартными именами Python, как, например, `list`. Могут быть проблемы...